# Reading selected ITEMS from Dynamically Created ListBox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have created ListBox's Dynamically in a panel and i want to read the selected item from the Listbox created dynamically . below is the code that i used to create the Dynamic Listbox. can anyone please help me how to get the dynamically created listbox and then read the item selected.                                                                                'protected void GotoReport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (TreeNode tndim in tvCubedef.CheckedNodes)
        {

            lbFilter.Items.Add(tndim.Text);

        }
        foreach (ListItem item in lbFilter.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }

        panFilter.Controls.Clear();
        connstr2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        conn2.ConnectionString = connstr2;
        conn2.Open();
        CubeCollection CubeList = conn2.Cubes;
        string cb = ddlCubeList.SelectedItem.Text;

        foreach (ListItem li in lbFilter.Items)
        {

            ListBox listb = new ListBox();
            ListItem Memlist = new ListItem();
            listb.SelectionMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
            listb.Height = 150;
            listb.Width = 250;

            string Repl1 = li.Value.Replace("[", "");
            string Repl2 = Repl1.Replace("]", "");
            string[] DimMember = Repl2.Split('.');
            foreach (Member dimem in CubeList[cb].Dimensions[DimMember[0]].Hierarchies[DimMember[1]].Levels[DimMember[2]].GetMembers())
            {

                Memlist.Text = dimem.Name;
                listb.Items.Add(Memlist);
                panFilter.Controls.Add(listb);

            }

        }


    } '
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event-handler dynamically:

```
listb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listb_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Of course you also need to provide this method:

```
protected void listb_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listb = (ListBox) sender;
}
```

Are you recreating this `ListBox` **on every postback** (as you should) in `page_load` at the latest and with same `ID` as before?

Comment: @Tim.. thanks for your response. actually i dont need to add en event handler... what i was trying to do is, i will add the  lbFilter fields in a Listbox then when i click a go button it will create the dynamic List boxes with the values for each fields. ex. if i add country,state in lbFilter then 2 dynamic List boxes will be created with country and state vales... so once it done then i will select the item from those 2 List box and construct my query in my where clause. so that part i am strugling to find the libox i created and read those values.hope this give a brief idea about my request

Comment: So have you tried `panFilter.Controls.OfType<ListBox>()` to find all your listboxes in the panel?

Comment: nope i have not tried . frankly speaking i am very new to asp.net, so i am learning asp.net little by little... could you please give me some code syntax for the above your idea using 'panFilter.Controls.OfType<ListBox>()'

Comment: @user1849129: Above is a linq-query, you need at least .NET 3.5 and add `using system.Linq;`. The query returns all listboxes in your panel(so it filters by type). You can use `foreach` to iterate them or use `ToArray()` to materialize the query to a `ListBox[]`. The best in ASP.NET is to avoid dynamic controls at all if you can. So in most cases you should simply switch the visibility of already declared controls(on the aspx markup). Note that invisible controls are not rendered at all to the client(html). That would make your code more readable, maintainable and less error-prone.

Comment: @tom... thanks again..yes i am using .net 4 framework. an thanks for your advice...but i had to use this dynamic option in my page :)... and i written below not sure this will work or not...  'Dictionary<string, string> selectedfil = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (ListBox ctl in panFilter.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in ctl.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                        selectedfil.Add(li.Text, li.Value);
                    
                }
                
            } '

Comment: @user1849129: You can replace the loop with `var selItem = ctl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().First(i => i.Selected); selectedfil.Add(selItem.Text,selItem.Value);`.